# Misalignment of great circle path with specified coordinates in Azimuthal Equidistant projection using Cartopy

Tags: python, matplotlib, cartopy

I am working on a project using Python's Cartopy and Matplotlib libraries to plot the great circle path between two points on an Azimuthal Equidistant projection.

Here's the Python code I'm using:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import numpy as np

def great_circle_points(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2, num_points):
    lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2 = np.radians([lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2])
    dlat = lat2 - lat1
    dlon = lon2 - lon1
    fractions = np.linspace(0, 1, num_points)
    a = np.sin(dlat/2)**2 + np.cos(lat1) * np.cos(lat2) * np.sin(dlon/2)**2
    delta_sigma = 2 * np.arctan2(np.sqrt(a), np.sqrt(1-a))

    lat = np.arctan2(
        np.sin(lat1) * np.cos(delta_sigma * fractions) + np.sin(lat2) * np.sin(delta_sigma * fractions),
        np.sqrt((np.cos(lat1) + np.cos(lat2) * np.cos(delta_sigma * fractions))**2 + (np.cos(lat2) * np.sin(delta_sigma * fractions))**2)
    )
    lon = lon1 + np.arctan2(
        np.sin(delta_sigma * fractions) * np.sin(lon2 - lon1),
        np.cos(lat1) * np.cos(delta_sigma * fractions) - np.sin(lat1) * np.sin(delta_sigma * fractions) * np.cos(lon2 - lon1)
    )

    lat = np.degrees(lat)
    lon = np.degrees(lon)

    return lat, lon

lat1, lon1 = -33.9715, 18.6021  # Cape Town
lat2, lon2 = -42.8364, 147.5075  # Hobart
num_points = 1001

latitudes, longitudes = great_circle_points(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2, num_points)

plt.figure(figsize=[10, 10])
#ccrs.Orthographic(), ccrs.Stereographic(), ccrs.LambertAzimuthalEqualArea(), or ccrs.Gnomonic().
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.AzimuthalEquidistant(central_latitude=90, central_longitude=0))
ax.set_global()
ax.coastlines()

# Plotting the great circle points.
ax.plot(longitudes, latitudes, 'r', transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
plt.plot(lon1, lat1, 'bo', markersize=7, transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
plt.plot(lon2, lat2, 'ro', markersize=7, transform=ccrs.Geodetic())

plt.show()
```

This code successfully generates an Azimuthal Equidistant projection with coastlines, and it correctly plots two points representing specific locations on Earth (as specified via latitude and longitude inputs). These points are correctly located relative to the coastlines.

However, the great circle path that is generated doesn't start and end at these location points as it should. Instead, it appears to be offset from the correct starting and ending points.

This is the output of my current:
[Azimuthal Projection with incorrect great circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEQq8.png)

I've tried adjusting the coordinates, but I believe they are correct as the points appear at the correct locations on the map.

How can I adjust the great circle path so that it correctly starts and ends at the specified locations?

Thank you in advance for your help.

I have tried changing the two locations and a few other things but without success.  What I expected to see was the great circle path start on one location and end on the other.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this has anything to do with Matplotlib or Cartopy, you should probably debug your algorithm first.

Doing the same with `Pyproj`:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import pyproj

lat1, lon1 = -33.9715, 18.6021   # Cape Town
lat2, lon2 = -42.8364, 147.5075  # Hobart
num_points = 1001
```

Sampling points along the great circle:

```py
geod = pyproj.Geod(ellps="WGS84")

coords = geod.npts(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2, num_points, initial_idx=0, terminus_idx=0)
lons, lats = zip(*coords)
```

Visualize the result:

```py
map_proj = ccrs.AzimuthalEquidistant(central_latitude=90, central_longitude=0)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,6), subplot_kw=dict(projection=map_proj))

ax.set_global()
ax.coastlines(alpha=.4)

ax.plot(lons, lats, 'r-', transform=ccrs.Geodetic())

ax.plot(lon1, lat1, 'ro', ms=7, mec="k", transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
ax.plot(lon2, lat2, 'ro', ms=7, mec="k", transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
```

[image]